# how to programmatically pass my own ServletConfig to a servlet

Tags: jetty, servlet-3.0

This is an example about embedding jetty 7 from:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty

```
public class OneServletContext
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server(8080);

        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/");
        server.setHandler(context);

        context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new HelloServlet()),"/*");

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

The server HelloServlet will be initialized with a call to init(ServletConfig config);

How can I tell Jetty to pass my own ServletConfig to HelloServet?
(I don't have a web.xml file, and I don't want to have one)

```
Note:
I think that in Jetty6, you can call context.setInitParameter("my_key", "my_value");
but this function does not exists in Jetty7.

I've tried with context.getServletContext.setInitParameter("my_key", "my_value");
but I get an exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException was thrown.
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.setInitParameter(ServletContextHandler.java:569)
```

Answer (score 7):

solved:

```
ServletHolder helloServletHolder = new ServletHolder(new HelloServlet());
helloServletHolder.setInitParameter("my_key", "my_value");
context.addServlet(helloServletHolder,"/*");
```